# I feel like I'm abusing the Triage queue; Editing questions as I go through

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, quality-improvement

In the past couple of days, I've started to feel "guilty" as I go through the Triage queue. For a good handful of the questions I know, as soon I see them, that they need help and I know that I can help. Therefore, I open the questions in a new tab and edit them. A person simply going through Triage would likely normally click "Should Be Improved" and move on.

Now I'm stuck in this situation in which I don't know what the "best" way to handle these specific questions is.

Should I:

1. Open the question in a new tab, click "Should Be Improved" and then go improve it? (If I improve it after clicking "Should Be Improved," does it still show up in another review queue?)
2. Open the question in a new tab, improve it, then come back and click "Looks OK" or "Skip"?
3. Stop letting the side of me who wants to edit control me and just click "Should Be Improved" and move on?

Or can we possibly improve the Triage process by:

- Adding a prompt, after you select "Should Be Improved" that says something like, "Can you improve this question?" or "Would you like to improve this question?"
- Adding a new button next to "Should Be Improved" that says "Let Me Improve This Question"?

I'd be interested to hear if other people succumb to this same issue when going through Triage and what their thoughts are.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to be editing bad questions, rather than directing certain questions to people who can edit them then *you're in the wrong queue*.

Go to the H&I queue, or the first/late posts queues, and you'll find lots of questions that need editing, and be in a queue in which you're *intended* to spend time editing them.

Comment: Yes, I spend time in all queues. However, once I'm tapped out for the day in those and wind up in Triage, the wants-to-help side of me still is in affect.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen If you're not actually interested in triaging posts, and are instead simply interested in editing posts that need editing then *don't use the triage queue*.  Every queue isn't for everyone.  The main reason for having as many queues as there are is (at least partly) because different people are suited to different types of moderation activities.  If you prefer editing posts to triaging posts then *don't use the triage queue*.  It's that simple.  If you are just looking for places to find posts to edit, there are plenty of places to go besides the triage queue.

Comment: Servy, I think your points are all valid except I'm not sure he is "not actually interested in triaging posts", but not sure what to do when he comes across one that he is able to fix. I've had that thought, as well, why walk away from something that you can fix myself. It feels "wrong" to say it needs to be fixed and pass it along if you can take care of it yourself. Which leads to his second thought "Or can we possibly improve the Triage process by..."

Comment: @codeMagic If that feels wrong to you then *you're not interested in triaging posts*, you're interested in handling posts that have already been triaged.  Now that's *fine*.  Some people like triaging, some people like actually handling posts.  Turning the triage queue into a queue for fixing posts, instead of triaging them however, is *defeating the purpose of that queue*.  Saying, "I like this other queue better, so can you turn this queue that I don't like into one that functions like this other queue that I do like?" isn't sensible.

Comment: @Servy As Michael already said, they've *already* gone through the rest of the queues, and ended up in Triage. Fixing the posts in the Triage queue is a net benefit to the site, regardless of the original purpose of the queue. The queue exists to quickly triage questions, for those who are not interested in editing. Performing the job of the triager *and* the improver is not 'defeating the purpose of the queue', rather, it is going above and beyond what is required. *There is no negative to improving questions in the triage queue*.

Comment: Should we rename the Triage queue to something else then? Maybe Triage & Help & Improvement Queue? ;)

Answer (score 5):

The act of triage is to determine what level of help the question needs.  You do not actually work on the thing in the triage process.  Questions that you know need help should be marked "Should Be Improved" and if enough people feel that way then it is moved to the place where people can help them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not abuse necessarily, but you have your priorities wrong.

By clicking the "Should be improved" button, you allow these questions to move forward in the cycle.

Instead, consider editing one of the literally millions of questions that aren't in triage that need attention. Here is a list of searches that will probably keep you busy for several lifetimes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dont
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=havent
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cant
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22whats%22
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youve
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youre

Comment: This advice is fine for users who have more than 2000 rep, so that their edits are not reviewed. Using those kinds of queries before attaining 2000 rep is not recommended, in my opinion.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It doesn't matter how much rep you have IMO, as long as you are doing a thorough job (which the OP appears to be doing). I completely forgot that the queues are unlocked at only 500 rep, actually.