# Editing the posts yourself while reviewing Triage queue

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

While reviewing in the Triage queue, if I see that a post needs to be edited, what should I do?

‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍      ‍‍ ‍‍**1.** Should I click on **`Requires Editing`**?
 
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍**2.** Or should I *edit it myself*?
 
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍**3.** Or should I do both?
 
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍**4.** Or should I *edit it myself* and click on **`Looks Good`**?
 
 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍**5.** Or anything else?

Comment: You can do both. However, the task in Triage is to merely categorize posts.

Comment: You should click "Requires Editing".

Comment: @honk I can do both `1` and `2` but  then wouldn't it be a wrong review since the post/s may not need to be edited anymore?

Comment: At the moment of time when you reviewed it, it required editing, the fact you have done it as well is a nice bonus, but not necessarily. You review the post as it is, not as it will be after you've edited it.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama: As Draken says: Review the post as it is first. Then you may take any additional action.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289801/i-feel-like-im-abusing-the-triage-queue-editing-questions-as-i-go-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you can edit the posts to a good state, you should go for option 4. If you go for option 3, and <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> is the outcome of the review, it will *unnecessarily* [end up in the Help & Improvement review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323945/fixing-the-disconnect-between-vlq-and-triage). While it doesn't hinder to have a fresh pair of eyes looking at the question, we don't want to waste reviewers' time, especially given the current backlog.

Of course, if you'd like to follow the instructions to the letter, you need to choose option 1, and option 2 (editing the question) is optional. This is also the way to go if you have less than 2000 reputation and your edit needs to be peer reviewed (the Triage queue is already accessible from 500 reputation).