# Changes to "Requires Editing" button in the triage queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

**The problem:**

People treat "Requires Editing" button as "OP needs to clarify his question" button. Most of the questions in the "Help and Improvement" are not salvageable through editing by community members, they should have being flagged as `too broad` / `unclear` / `off-topic`, etc.

**Proposed solution:**

For 500-1999 points users replace the "Requires Editing" with a "Edit" button. If you think that a question is salvageable through editing, then do it yourself. The edits will move to the edit approval queue (the same way they do now). Give 500-1999 users access to the "Help and Improvement" queue. 2000+ users will still have the "Requires Editing" button. My intent is that more experienced users will be able to use this button to send questions they don't want to edit themselves to 500-1999 users so they can edit them and get points.

**EDIT 1:** If we exposing 500-1999 users to the H&I queue then when they reach 2000 points they'll know what "Requires Editing" button actually does. So they will be able to use it more wisely.

A drawback of this approach is that right now the edit approval queue is blocking. If more 500-1999 users will start editing questions it can become a problem. May be there will be a need to enable concurrent edits: an approver will have to choose the best edit or mash few edits together.

**EDIT 2:** This question has nothing to do with [Replace “Requires Editing” with “Edit” in Triage if the reviewer has Editing Privileges [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317246/replace-requires-editing-with-edit-in-triage-if-the-reviewer-has-editing-pri). It is pretty much the opposite.

**EDIT 3:** I presume that "Requires Editing" is supposed to work as described in this [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317246/replace-requires-editing-with-edit-in-triage-if-the-reviewer-has-editing-pri#answer-295674). I.e.:

> Is the question in pretty bad shape? Can you imagine yourself editing the question into something that can be answered? How about some other random editor with perhaps more knowledge of the specific area, or more patience for lousy writing, or both?
>
> If so, hit **Requires Editing**.
>
> **Do not** choose "Requires Editing" if you *know* the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author.

**TL;DR: The workflow after the proposed changes:**

1. A 2000+ user clicks "Requires Editing".
2. The question is passed to the H&I queue.
3. A 500-1999 user, who has the access to H&I queue now, edits the question.
4. The question is passed to the Suggested Edits queue.
5. The edit gets approved.
6. The 500-1999 users gets 2 internet points.

Notes: 500-1999 will not have "Requires Editing" button only a "Edit" button. Which they already have if they open a question in outside of the Triage queue in another tab (so not much changes here). 2000+ users will have access to H&I queue the same way they have now.

Comment: Unfortunately the help test in triage says *Requires Editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable* so this would cause confusion unless SO finally changes it (has been asked for over year now iirc)

Comment: This [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) says otherwise. `Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author.` AFIAK OP is not even notified that his questions was marked as "Requires Editing".

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317246 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289802/5764553 (these are both more specific to >2k users). Essentially, Triage is just for making quick decisions about what to do with questions (hence, _triage_). Actually improving questions is beyond the scope of the Triage queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver That FAQ was not written by a mod but @Shog9 wrote in a comment there `We're considering linking to this from review;` so it's pretty much an official FAQ. The fact that it contradicts the official help is really weird. I trust that FAQ more because because pressing "Requires Editing" for questions which need clarification from OP makes no sense.

Comment: The company doesn't give a hoot about how reviewers vote in the Triage queue.  Its only role is as a data feed for the [newnav] feature, they only care about "looks good".  The probable reason such basic flaws don't get fixed.  A question that's been voted "unsalvageable" by everybody still shows up in my Interesting page view.  It is never interesting.  So H&I is just a waste of time, don't bother.

Comment: How does this FR solve the problem? The [*only way* posts get into the Help & Improvement queue is for them to be marked as "Requires Editing" in Triage](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659). Thus, your proposed feature would eliminate the Help and Improvement queue. That's certainly not what's desired by SE. I agree, it's broken. But, it's also clear that SE doesn't care. In [more than a year and a half](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895) ([2](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546)) they haven't bothered to change a few characters of text to make it clear to users what "Requires Editing" means.

Comment: @Makyen the question you link to is totally oposite...