# It seems many misunderstand the "Requires Editing" option in Triage review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

As it stands, the immediate definition of "Requires Editing" is:

> for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing

I understand that this is clearly stating "questions that **you** can make clear" but I feel that it can be taken as an expression of "something that can be done" and not literally **you**. - A possible problem for someone who may not have a great understanding of English.

This I find is largely interpreted--myself included when I first started--as:

"This question needs more information to make it clear and answerable. -by having the OP edit the question with just that."

But, if you take a look at the [detailed guide for triaging questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674), it states the following;

> Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author.

I've just noticed people making this decision in the triage queue and can't help but think it was due to a misunderstanding that I made when I was first getting into reviewing.

Should there be a slightly more detailed definition under the (more) section?

I think it would be beneficial for the (more) section to have at least one extra line below each definition explaining a very common "this is not used for _" or something that better describes the use of that button.

I am now aware of [the same question asked here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues) but my case is that even with the edits made since then, it can still be clearer and have more included **on the page** as many people may not bother to follow the link to the detailed guide.

Comment: The proper guidance *is* on the page now. These are the changes that [Shog9 implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366583). It says very clearly that "Requires Editing" is for questions that *you* can make clearer by editing. You are not the OP.

Comment: @CodyGray I suppose that is clear but I did not even interpret it like that until you have pointed it out right now. I think it may also be a problem for people who don't speak English as their primary language or just don't understand it well.

Comment: Fair enough. Propose an alternative wording that will be more clear, and we'll see if we can poke Shog9 enough to get it changed? Remember, the shorter the better, because we want people to read it.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the suggestion, I made the edits.

Comment: Personally, I'd get rid of the *Requires Editing* choice. It is used incorrectly 99 times out of 100 no matter what guidance is given. Instead, give the reviewer a choice to personally edit it for improvement as one of the actions.

Comment: @rsjaffe I actually just read a good question talking about [personal edits in the triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289801/i-feel-like-im-abusing-the-triage-queue-editing-questions-as-i-go-through).

Comment: @Jake I see their point. In that case, just get rid of the *Requires Editing* choice. It's a source of wasted work.

Comment: What if "Requires Editing" was replaced with an "Edit" button? would that not drive home the idea that it's for things *you* can fix?

Comment: Agreed, @Kevin. I've wanted to make that argument so many times. The counter-argument is, of course, that you aren't supposed to be *fixing* problems when you are triaging them. That's an entirely different review queue. The counter-counter-argument is, maybe it doesn't matter. We're not talking about life-and-death here, and seconds don't matter. The goal is to clean up the site and get Franz Kafka out of the review queues.

Comment: @CodyGray Either an **Edit** button or *no button at all*. I don't care which. But get rid of that evil *Requires Editing* button! It's broken and beyond repair.

Comment: @CodyGray How about an **edit** button that brings up a dialogue saying "Would you like to edit now or push this post into a queue for other members of the community to edit?"  That way it can still be triaged, or, if a user wants to stop triaging for a bit to do the edit themselves, they have the option? That seems like it has the best of both options, the only downside I can think of is that there's two buttons to click; edit, then the option. But since editing is much less frequently needed than something that makes the post unsalvageable, I don't think two menus would slow things down any.

Comment: @Davy Eh, I am not so sure that adding more dialog boxes is the best approach. It just creates more friction. That's the "lazy" approach to design. Better to decide what workflow we want, and then design the system around that. If you want to allow people to edit from Triage, then let them edit. If you don't, then that should not be an option. If you *really* want to edit from Triage, you don't need a new dialog box for it. You just open the post in a new window/tab, and then make your edit.

Comment: This problem, which undermines the *claimed* purpose of the Triage system, has repeatedly been complained about, with SE not really addressing it. I've come to the conclusion that SE don't really want to fix it, because they don't really want questions from new users to be closed.

Comment: Thank you for re-opening this discussion @Jake, I feel I encounter examples of the misinterpretation you describe almost daily: posts which would require additional information from the OP ending the Triage review with _Requires Editing_ without anyone editing the post.

Comment: I can't search right now, nor do I want to, but the "Requires Editing" button requiring clarification has been a long standing issue. Same with the "Looks OK". It's been years and the topic has been brought up at least a few times. Nothing has really come out of it except people with utmost familiarity with what the triage system does explaining to the single person who was misled by the button title what it actually does (well, *obviously* "Requires editing" puts the question in the editing queue). Which doesn't help when the next person comes in.

Comment: @CodyGray Experienced users can choose to make a (keyboard) shortcut (for example, via an option in the setting)

Comment: @user202729 What does that have to do with anything I said? A keyboard shortcut doesn't solve the *design* problem. I'm actually not sure what problem you see a keyboard shortcut as solving here. The point of my last comment is that this feature needs to be designed. We need to decide what we want, what the proper workflow should be, and then force that. Having two parallel, incompatible workflows is a design failure, and this cannot be compensated for by adding another dialog box, a keyboard shortcut, or whatever else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> It seems many misunderstand the “Requires Editing” option in Triage review

Oh yes, they do.
And it's not like this is something new. Here's a list of related meta posts a quick search brought up:

- [Can we have more clear instructions for review queues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340687)
- [How to fix triage! (?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376364)
- [Help tip for "Requires Editing" is incorrect in the Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362351)
- [Adopt a consistent policy on what "Requires Editing" means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546)
- [The incorrect usage of "Requires Editing" is still causing problems. Can we do something about it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372485)
- [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for "Requires Editing"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319128)
- [Replace "Requires Editing" button text with "Needs help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346194)
- [Triage "Requires Editing" description is (still) misleading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366334)
- [Changes to "Requires Editing" button in the triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357470)
- [Replace "Requires Editing" with "Edit" in Triage if the reviewer has Editing Privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317246)
- [Change triage guidelines for "requires editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895)
- [Adopt a consistent policy on what "Requires Editing" means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546)

## UGH, COME ON!

The misuse of "Requires Editing" has no end, and I feel like this is a combination of:

- A horribly mislabeled button.

  > **Requires Editing** for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing

  Doesn't tell you by whom or in what volume, while in reality it means **by people other than the author**, which in turn means that **only formatting and language issues** can be fixed.
- A brutally labeled button.

  > **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site

  If a question shows research and effort but lacks some crucial information, it cannot be answered as-is, but that doesn't mean we're going to remove it from the site, as that issue is very fixable by the OP, and we have enough mechanisms in place to allow that.
  I think many people are simply too reluctant to choose this option for questions that lack information but are otherwise high-quality.
- **There is no option to request clarification from the OP**
  The action we would *want* to take is closing the question with the appropriate reason, to either be edited and reopened, or eventually deleted. We have these mechanisms in place here and now, and "Unsalvageable" pretty much does that.
  The problem is just that this is not mentioned anywhere in the UI.

Consider this (dark theme aside):

[image: mockup]

- Looks OK: same as before
- Formatting Issues: new name for "Requires Editing"
- Needs Clarification: does exactly the same as "Unsalvageable" while sounding less brutal
- Unsalvageable: same as before
- Skip: same as before

This is a simple change that would merely affect the frontend and nothing else.
Dear powers that be, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) pretty please?

Comment: I think this is in the right direction as I find it's kind of pointless to pass a question on to further judgment to close a question simply because it doesn't have enough information or clarification from the OP. This also helps people choose easier. I think this will be a practical solution if it was paired with some kind of a tutorial modal that replaced the (more) section with a more detailed explanation of the options.

Comment: I feel there's also one more missing option, a "Let me edit!" option.  Its not uncommon for me to have a very clear idea what edit is required -- even a simple and fast one (e.g. fix formatting).  This also means I don't have to worry that the Suggested Edits queue won't understand what edit might be required (especially as a post-2k user when my edits immediately apply).  However, there is no edit link in triage, and I have to open the question in another window to do it....

Comment: Sometimes I find a question with good research and intent, but maybe missing some code from the OP that can make it easier for people to answer. So, the `Needs Clarification` feature is essential in those cases. I mean it would be plain wrong to tag them `Unsavageable` while `Looks OK` wouldn't help the OP get an answer.

Comment: @Anakin Under the current system, marking them as "unsalvageable" would be the perfectly right course of action though, to get the question closed as a variation of "needs MCVE", and then hopefully edited by the OP and subsequently reopened. It's just that the "unsalvageable" button sounds like the end of the line, which does absolutely not have to be the case.

Comment: I was unfortunately banned from review because of my misunderstanding of Requires Editing. Feel free to add [my thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393127/6619250) in!

Comment: In addition to the above, I believe a lot of users shy away from the "Unsalvageable" button due to the belief that would be closing/deleting the question and the negative impact that could have on a new user, especially when their question was salvageable.