# I just failed an audit, but I don't understand why

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

So, I just failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26646582) *(Whoops!)*. But I don't understand:

[image]

In my eyes, the question looks okay after some editing, so I selected *requires editing*, but I should've chosen *spam or offensive*. Can someone explain?

---

UPDATE: Turns out this is a bug that needs to be fixed. <<added bug tag>>

Comment: Another bad "spam" audit? Most likely, the OP was a spammer and some/all of their posts were deleted as spam (including non-spam posts); I've seen this happen before. Just wait for a mod to confirm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Summary from comments:

> By Cody Gray ♦:
>
> It was posted by a known troll, and a moderator used the spam flag to nuke it before destroying the account. They should have used the "rude/abusive" flag, which has the same effect, but doesn't allow it to be used as an audit. (In some sense, it was spam, as this troll has been spamming the site repeatedly with the same question, but that's not something a reviewer could or would be expected to know.) 
> As ever, it's a bad audit, since audits are supposed to be obvious. Fixed now.

---

> By Martijn Pieters ♦
>
> Sorry, this was my error. It’s not so much a troll as someone who has an extraordinary tone-deafness towards “no longer welcome” combined with a narrow single-minded focus on a single topic rarely seen, reposting several times a week. They have been trying to solve the same narrow task for over a year now and seem incapable of learning on their own. Anyway, I tried out a new tool built by a fellow moderator to expedite the regular clearing of accounts and forgot this also put the post into the audit queue. 
> I’ll review the past few posts involved to see if I need to clear more such posts.

Comment: I don't see why this would help.

Comment: @zixuan Maybe not, but it's what I want to accept.

Comment: I'm curious. Why has this answer, which quotes correctly  two comments by two moderators, downvoted so heavily? Comments can be deleted, and never seen again by the community but answers are not (usually) hard deleted.

Comment: @AnnZen Was there any indication that the information quoted in this answer was intended to be private?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the two comments are still visible underneath Ryan M's answer. They were posted by two mods, if the comments were meant to be private nobody but the author would be able to see them.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No.

Comment: @AnnZen I was trying to find any reason that the answer by you was downvoted. I don't see why changing ephemeral comments to a complete answer would be downvoted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 19):

First off: You're absolutely right that there's nothing spammy or offensive about this post.  That's clearly wrong, and the expectation that you should have picked that is incorrect.  Hopefully this audit can be removed so as not to mislead people.

That said, a heads-up: "Requires editing" must be an edit that could be performed by *someone other than the person asking the question*.  The question must have all the required information, but need some sort of formatting or grammar help (questions that need code fences are a great example of this).  A quick glance through your review history finds things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26646051), which looks like it could probably use some more information from the asker (like how `con` is defined) to create a minimal, reproducible example.

This question looks better than that one, and this is honestly not a good audit.  It looks like the answer is a typo (extra closing `}` bracket after the last `)`) which may have caused the downvotes.  Overall, I'd recommend being careful with "Requires editing" (some helpful meta posts: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389149/208273), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393128/208273)) for posts that need more than formatting/grammar help, but otherwise not worrying about this audit failure in particular.

Comment: It was posted by a known troll, and a moderator used the spam flag to nuke it before destroying the account. They should have used the "rude/abusive" flag, which has the same effect, but doesn't allow it to be used as an audit. (In some sense, it was spam, as this troll has been spamming the site repeatedly with the same question, but that's not something a reviewer could or would be expected to know.) As ever, it's a bad audit, since audits are supposed to be obvious. Fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, this was my error. It’s not so much a troll as someone who has an extraordinary tone-deafness towards “no longer welcome” combined with a narrow single-minded focus on a single topic rarely seen, reposting several times a week. They have been trying to solve the same narrow task for over a year now and seem incapable of learning on their own. Anyway, I tried out a new tool built by a fellow moderator to expedite the regular clearing of accounts and forgot this also put the post into the audit queue. I’ll review the past few posts involved to see if I need to clear more such posts.

Comment: @CodyGray Audits are supposed to obvious? Well, there's a time I chosen to close a post as *needs debugging details* because of its *Wall of code*, but failed the audit.

Comment: @AnnZen This is why I stopped Triage. It's super confusing. I only have 24 flags a day, and when I run out of flags, and a post is "Unsalvageable", what do I do?

Comment: @10Rep Oh, I see.

Comment: @10Rep You stop reviewing for the day. There's nothing to do.

Comment: @pppery You have a point :). But nevertheless, if that was fixed, a lot more reviewing would be done. One simple fix would be to make the unsalvegable button **not** raise a flag, and instead do something else.